# Linear regression forcing one specific value

Tags: python, scikit-learn, conditional-statements, regression

I want to calculate a simple linear regression where I need to force a particular value for one point. Namely, I have `x` and `y` arrays, and I want my regression `f(x)` to force `f(x[-1]) == y[-1]` - that is, the prediction over the last element of `x` should be equal to the last element of `y`.

Is there a way to do it using Python and scikit-learn?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just fit an OLS and add the residual on the last y to the fitted values?

Comment: It might help to get some context on why you need it to pass exactly through the last element

Comment: @jwde it sounds like that would shift the entire line in one direction (up or down) and could lead to some very big errors. The question boils down to finding the slope that minimizes the errors given that the line passes through `(x[-1], y[-1])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slightly roundabout trick that will do it.

Try re-centering your data, i.e. subtract x[-1], y[-1] from all datapoints so that x[-1], y[-1] is now the origin.

Now fit your data using sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression with fit_intercept set to False. This way, the data is fit so that the line is forced to pass through the origin. Because we've re-centered the data, the origin corresponds to x[-1], y[-1].

When you use the model to make predictions, subtract x[-1] from any datapoint for which you are making a prediction, then add y[-1] to the resulting prediction, and this will give you the same results as forcing your model to pass through x[-1], y[-1].

This is a little roundabout but it's the simplest way that occurs to me to do it using the sklearn linear regression function (without writing your own).

Answer (score 3):

The suggestion from HappyDog is great as a quick way to get a fit however I'd like to introduce another method which doesn't require any manipulation of your data. The method will use the [**`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) method to fit your data.

First, we need to realize that a normal linear regression will find A and B such that y=Ax+B provides the best fit to the input data. Your requirements state that the fit *must* pass through the final point in your sample data set. Essentially we'll be dropping a line that passes through your final point and rotating it around this point until we can minimize the errors.

Take a look at the point-slope equation for a line: `y-yi = m*(x-xi)` where `(xi, yi)` is any point on that line. If we make the substution that this `(xi, yi)` point is the final point from your data set and solve for `y`, we get `y=m*(x-xf)+yf`. This is the model we will fit.

Translating this model to a python-function, we have:

```py
def model(x, m, xf, yf):
  return m*(x-xf)+yf
```

We create a mock-data set for this example and just for demonstration purposes we will significantly shift the final y-value:

```py
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = x + np.random.uniform(0, 3, len(x))
y[-1] += 10
```

We're almost ready to perform the fit. The `curve_fit` function expects a callable function (`model`) to fit, the x and y data, and a list of the guesses of each parameter we are trying to fit. Since our `model` accepts two extra "constant" arguments (`xf` and `yf`), we use `functools.partial` to "set" these arguments based on our data.

```py
partial_model = functools.partial(model, xf=x[-1], yf=y[-1])
p0 = [y[-1]/x[-1]] # Initial guess for m, as long as xf != 0
```

Now we can fit!

```py
best_fit, covar = curve_fit(partial_model, x, y, p0=p0)
print("Best fit:", best_fit)
y_fit = model(x, best_fit[0], x[-1], y[-1])
intercept = model(0, best_fit[0], x[-1], y[-1]) # The y-intercept
```

And we look at the results:

```py
plt.plot(x, y, "g*") # Input data will be green stars
plt.plot(x, y_fit, "r-") # Fit will be a red line
plt.legend(["Sample Data", f"y=mx+b ; m={best_fit[0]:.4f}, b={intercept:.4f}"])
plt.show()
```

Putting all this together in one code block and including imports gives:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import functools

def model(x, m, xf, yf):
  return m*(x-xf)+yf

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = x + np.random.uniform(0, 3, len(x))
y[-1] += 10

partial_model = functools.partial(model, xf=x[-1], yf=y[-1])
p0 = [y[-1]/x[-1]] # Initial guess for m, as long as xf != 0

best_fit, covar = curve_fit(partial_model, x, y, p0=p0)
print("Best fit:", best_fit)
y_fit = model(x, best_fit[0], x[-1], y[-1])
intercept = model(0, best_fit[0], x[-1], y[-1]) # The y-intercept

plt.plot(x, y, "g*") # Input data will be green stars
plt.plot(x, y_fit, "r-") # Fit will be a red line
plt.legend(["Sample Data", f"y=mx+b ; m={best_fit[0]:.4f}, b={intercept:.4f}"])
plt.show()
```

[image: bestfit]

We see a line passing through the final point, as required, and have found the best slope to represent this dataset.

Comment: This is good. Same method as HappyDog but transforms the data and sets intercept to 0 in the model function rather than on the data